# converting 4 pin TRRS headset jack to 5 pin XLR headset jack

Tags: xlr

First off, I hope this is mostly on topic.

I am in the process of modifying the design of a raspberry pi like device to fit it with a 5 pin xlr jack for connecting a stereo intercom headset. I know the pinouts of the two connectors are basically compatible, meaning I can connect headphone ground to headphone ground, right to right, etc.

I was wondering if the levels coming out of a consumer audio product using a TRRS jack would be at all compatible with a pro level headset or if I would have to use some sort of level shifter.

Edit: I have googled this, but all it comes up with is questions about connecting an ipod to a mixer via a 3.5mm to xlr converter. No info specifically about headsets.

thanks

Comment: Would love an answer for this! Am looking to connect a 4-pin headset in the same way, only in mono over both headphone channels. Pin out is easy for sure, just don't want to blow any preamps.

Answer (score 1):

It will most probably work fine. The only difference would likely be the impedance, pro level equipment typically having higher impedance (200-600 Ω) than consumer products (< 100 Ω). All this means is that a consumer device may be easier to drive (higher volume in headphones) and that the microphone may put out a stronger signal. This all depends on the type of preamp/output amp in use, however. This article is an excellent source of information: http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/jan03/articles/impedanceworkshop.asp.

All in all, I would say: go ahead and try it!